# Using Fancybox - Opening an iframe, need rounded corners in IE

Tags: iframe, fancybox, rounded-corners

Using CSS I can get the iframe popup to have rounded corners in all browsers besides IE. I have tried to use a few jQuery plugins for rounded corners, and applying them to #fancybox-outer with no success.

Does anyone please have a solution for rounded corners and fancybox (iframe) using IE. A demo would even be better!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about iframe, but i'm using this code:

```
$("a.fancy").fancybox({
    'titlePosition' :   'inside',
    'overlayShow'   :   true,
    'overlayOpacity':   0.5,
    'overlayColor'  :   '#000',
    'onComplete'    :   function() {
        DD_roundies.addRule('#fancybox-title', '5px', true);
        DD_roundies.addRule('#fancybox-outer', '10px', true);
    }
});
```

with DD_roundies: http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/

Hope this helps :)